# How to hide "Name" column from Preview Pane style

Tags: xslt, designer

I'm trying to hide the `Name` column from the preview pane view in a form library.

What I've done in my view on SPD is change the field used in the view list (the area you hover over) to this:

> ```
>     <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" onclick='OpenDialog({$thisNode/@ID}, "{$thisNode/@Titre1}")'>
>       <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Titre1" />
>     </a>
> ```

But in the area where the information is displayed I don't need the `Name` column and I'm trying to hide that.

```
                 <xsl:for-each select="ViewFields/FieldRef[not(@Explicit='TRUE')]">
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" width="190px"  class="ms-formlabel">
                        <nobr>
                          <xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/>
                        </nobr>
                      </td>
                      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px" id="n{position()}{$WPQ}">
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
```

My bindings look like this:

```
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="Titre1"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Sujet0"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Description_x0020__x0028_FR_x0029_"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Inscription"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Pr_x00e9_alable1"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Communaut_x00e9_0"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Livraison"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Dur_x00e9_e"/>
                <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/> <-- I want to get rid of this
            </ViewFields>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to open sharepoint designer and create a new custom "PrevForm".

There the complete form is rendered as normal table structure. You can just put "style='display:none'" in  and you are done.